# Elastic Search Remove Elements From Nested Object

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5

I have created an index in elastic search with a nested type field. and added documents into the index. Now I want to remove some elements from nested objects who match the condition using UpdateByQuery. I have tried the following query to but getting Conflict error.

```
POST test/_update_by_query
{
    "script": {
        "source": "for(int i= 0; i< ctx._source.address.size(); i++){if(ctx._source.address[i].city == params.city && ctx._source.address[i].state == params.state){ctx._source.address.remove(i)}}",
        "params": {
            "city": "Mumbai",
            "state": "Maharashtra"
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "term": {
                    "uid": "123"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

We have multiple documents whose uid is "123" Is any other option to remove elements from a nested object without getting a Conflict error? How I can solve this kindly Help me here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
POST test/documents/_update_by_query
{
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.address.removeIf(a -> a.city == params.city && a.state == params.state)",
        "params": {
            "city": "Mumbai",
            "state": "Maharashtra"
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "term": {
                    "uid": "123"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting following error: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"script_exception","reason":"runtime error","script_stack":["a -> a.city == params.city && a.state == params.state)","^---- HERE"],"script":"ctx._source.address.stream().removeIf(a -> a.city == params.city && a.state == params.state)","lang":"painless"}],"script":"ctx._source.address.stream().removeIf(a -> a.city == params.city && a.state == params.state)","lang":"painless","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"dynamic method [java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.Head, removeIf/1] not found"}},"status":500}

Comment: Thanks, @Val query is working fine. but I have one case in which I am using update_by_query and getting the following response: {"took":20,"timed_out":false,"total":2,"updated":2,"deleted":0,"batches":1,"version_conflicts":0,"noops":0,"retries":{"bulk":0,"search":0},"throttled_millis":0,"requests_per_second":-1,"throttled_until_millis":0,"failures":[]}    But Still my documents not updated. 
Can you please help me here to debug this issue? I can't able to understand what is wrong here?

Comment: sure @val Please check the comment .and kindly help me here to debug

Comment: Thanks, @Val to helping me.